# Laravel 5 triggering modal in view conditionally

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to check if user is login, if so then display some content, else i want to click a url or call modal.

```
@if(Auth::check())
    .............if user registered display here
@else
   I want to click the link below automatically....OR Call a view
   <a class="signin_link" href="{{ action('Auth\AuthController@login') }}" rel="get:Loginform"><i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:20px"></i></a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will redirect your user to the page you want:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    .............if user registered display here
@else
   //Redirect user to the link
   <script>window.location = "{{ action('Auth\AuthController@login') }}";</script>
@endif
```

And this would open your modal, if you are using bootstrap for example:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    .............if user registered display here
@else
   //Opening a bootstrap modal
   <script>$('#myModal').modal('show')</script>
@endif
```

**Note**: I assume that you already have your modal html somewhere on your page

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* do it in the view, you shouldn't. Instead, use the `auth` middleware (see https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php).

Here's an example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/this/route/needs/a/logged/in/user', 'PageController@account');
});
```

If there's no user logged in the visitor is redirected to the login page (which you can set in the middleware).